# My troubles creating MatLab table encoded in UTF-8

Tags: matlab, utf-8

I know that MatLab is not supposed to be ideal for this, but I wish to do some minimal work with my table-like data.dat file which looks like this:

```
ID,Name,Surname,Y,M,D,Num,Loc
1672399390,A,DULKINAS,1993,01,31,3019,Šiauliai
4157844163,D,SKARBALIUS,1993,12,08,3019,Tauragė
5541091033,E,LUKOŠEVIČIUS,1992,10,25,3019,Panevėžys
2005609387,M,DUBINSKAS,1991,03,31,3019,Kaunas
2716651285,P,ŽIEDELIS,1992,02,28,3019,Vilnius
```

Since the data is neatly formatted and separated by commas I decided to simply use `readtable('data.dat')` and work from there.

Problem 1. MatLab doesn't tell where the faulty line is. Since there were a couple of redundant commas, it just threw error **Each line of a text file must have the same number of delimiters**. I solved this by counting commas in every line using other tools and manually correcting them afterwards.

Problem 2. For some reason it renames the first variable `ID` (which is AFAIK a valid not reserved variable name) to `x__ID`
and gives a warning **Variable names were modified to make them valid MATLAB identifiers**. I don't really care about this one but it is weird.

Problem 3. Well the UTF-8 symbols are not displayed correctly. Moreover after trying my luck with [documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) and running `readtable('data.dat','FileEncoding','UTF-8')` it gives me a flat out error **Invalid parameter name: FileEncoding**. I am confused.

How should I approach this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is probably because you are using a version of matlab which is older than R2014b. The `FileEncoding` option [was added in R2014b](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#zmw57dd0e3162). If you check the documentation in your installation by `doc readtable` you probably find it missing.

The reason for the renaming of the ID is that it is interpreting [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the beginning of your unicode document as part of the name

Answer (score 1):

In addition, to address Problem 1 - the lines with extra commas are now flagged in the error message as of R2015a.  I added an extra comma into your data file on line 4, and here is the result:

```
>> readtable('data.dat', 'FileEncoding', 'UTF-8')
Error using readtable (line 129)
Reading failed at line 4. All lines of a text file must have the same number of delimiters. 
Line 4 has 8 delimiters, while preceding lines have 7.
```